# How can list files in tree format in command line on mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, ls

I'm using mac,and I want to display files in command line like this:
[image]

I know on linux `tree` command can make it,but this command doesn't exists on mac,anyone can tell me how to do this,thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/359727/454191

Comment: FWIW, I would definitely go with the `homebrew` solution suggested in the above comment - `homebrew` works very well.